# Programmable network diagnostic tools?

Tags: bandwidth, measurement

Are there any network diagnostics tools available that I can use to measure things like bandwidth.

As such there are a lot of tools which can do this, but I need one that I can embed in my application and program. Environment is WinCE but please list any generic tools also, preferably open source.

Comment: Not a programming question; however SolarWinds is a pretty big one for use.  Not sure of an open source solution for this though.

Comment: I have not read the terms & conditions but does not seem like StackOverflow is strictly for programming questions. In fact one reason for coming to StackOverflow is there is a good collection of good hackers you can ask things to.

Comment: @Sesh: Perhaps you should read the FAQ then. It /is/ for programming questions alone.

Comment: @ Rich - so if I ask  about a "Programmable" network diagnostic tool then it is not a programming question!!

Comment: @Sesh: You know as well as I do that was just a lame way to try and keep your question open.

Comment: @ Rich - sorry. And thanks to you I am closing the question un-answered. Trolls.

Comment: @Sesh: First, you have an answer. Second, in no way have I discouraged any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winpcap is a netwok packet capture library for windows which i believe is a port of a *nix library. It is (or was, at one point) used by the network traffic anlyzer Wireshark (a.k.a. Ethereal)

While I'm not certain if the library would work on WinCE, or whether it directly provides what your looking for, it may serve as a framework for any packet analysis that would need to be done in order to facilitate bandwidth use measurement